# Remove Action Bar icon but keep the UP button

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

I am developing an application which runs on both honeycomb and ice cream sandwich.
I want my action bar not to have the icon but keep the "up/home" button.

I used:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(0, ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
```

This removes the action bar icon but keeps the "up" button on ice cream sandwich.
But on honeycomb, it removes the "up" button as well.

Is there a way on honeycomb that allows me to keep the "up" button but get rid of the icon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will remove the menu icon and keep the indicator near it:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>    

<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: There's nothing on the question that indicates he is using ActionBarSherlock

Comment: So He could delete the ActionBarSherlock parts.